# asp .net click event with jquery ajax result null

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is my design code->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$='Button1']").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Default.aspx",
                data:'{ a: 2, b: 3 }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                   alert(data);

                   $("#weather-temp").html(data[0]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" Text="hi"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Result:
  its showing Null in alert box...
could anyone solve my problem....

Comment: First of all, why are you importing the jQuery library twice?

Comment: What does Default.aspx look like? Do you have it set up for AJAX? (http://www.asp.net/ajax).

Comment: Also your JSON is invalid

Comment: Open firefox --> click on firebug plugin --> access the page --> See the ajax call is happening or not and check what it is returning.

Comment: 1. Add breakpoint to your `Page_Load` in default.aspx to check. 2. Have you added `error` handler for your jquery' to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even attempt to fix this before asking here? There are developer tools in every modern browser that will let you watch the httprequests and see exactly where it is failing. You can also put breakpoints and watch expressions in so you can see what is happening and why. I would wager to bet that this problem will be fixed within minutes once you look at the dev tools.

In many cases where nothing is returned from the server it is because either your ajax call is not firing correctly, the path to the file is incorrect, the data you are sending is not valid json, or the backend script is syntaxically incorrect or just not functioning properly. You can Easily narrow down, where the problem stems from using your developer tools. Knowing where the error is is half the fight.

A couple of things about your code:

Only make one call to the jquery library. Typically people use the unminified version during development and swap it for the minified in production.

Why are you assigning Button1_Click to an onclick event in the markup when using jquery's .click in your script? (unless this is an aspx convention that I am unaware of as I am an mvc4 developer not aspx)

The json is invalid (remove the 's and surround strings (the values) with "").

You should use a post method instead of a get method if you are sending data to the server. This is not required but many consider this to be best practice particularly when trying to be restful.

Comment: Regarding the click event: The asp:Button control has an "onclick" method which webforms uses internally. So that part shouldn't be a problem, imo. "The json is invalid"? I would say that its an invalid object literal. The wrapping single quotes should be removed to make it a valid object literal. To make it a valid JSON string, it would look something like this: `'{ "a": 2, "b": 3 }'`.